# How do I make this a negative regex

Tags: regex

I have the following string that i want to replace parts of:

Blah blah Mr. [-user_first_name-] [-user_last_name-]

This will replace verything [- -]:

```
preg_replace('/[^\[-[a-z\d_\/A-Z. ]+-\]]/i', '', $body);
```

My goal is to replace everything that isn't in [- -]

Do you know how I can make this worth?

Comment: That regex isn't valid, is it? Shouldn't it be `preg_replace('%\[-[a-z\d_/A-Z. ]+-\]%', '', $body);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `preg_replace()`. Use `preg_match_all()` with the same regex and concatenate the results.

```
preg_match_all('%\[-[a-z\d_/A-Z. ]+-\]%', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = implode($result[0]);
```